# Area size in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Given an area id, is there a way to get size of this area from Overpass API?

For instance, I would like to know how many square kilometers New York has.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open feature request on Github: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/526

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my idea is totally wrong,

but what about

https://github.com/mapbox/earcut or

https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler

by the developer of leafletjs, Vladimir Agafonkin.

Are these libs able to process the area calculation for a polygon?